# What is the best way to store different types of data with a Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, promise

```
population: {[id: number]} = {}
places: {[id: string]} = {}

const promises = ['/api/population',
            '/api/data/Country',
            '/api/data/State', 
            '/api/data/County']
             .map(api => fetch(api)
```

`/api/population` should be stored in variable `population`.

`Country, State and County` should be stored in `places`.

I would like to store the data in its corresponding variable, what is the best way to do this using Promise.all(). How can I do this with foreach?

Comment: How do you store three values in a single variable?

Comment: Well, i was thinking of using forEach but I guess that not good because each API gets stored in different variables.

Comment: `forEach`  is almost always the wrong choice :-)

Comment: @Bergi haha. so true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` resolves with an array of its results wherein each result corresponds positionally to the input promise which resolved with it.

The most convenient way to assign the results to distinct identifiers is to use JavaScript's array destructuring syntax.

With `async`/`await`

```
const [populations, countries, states, counties] = await Promise.all([
   '/api/population',
   '/api/data/Country',
   '/api/data/State',
   '/api/data/County'
].map(api => fetch(api)));
```

With `.then`

```
Promise.all([
   '/api/population',
   '/api/data/Country',
   '/api/data/State',
   '/api/data/County'
].map(api => fetch(api)))
  .then(([populations, countries, states, counties]) => { });
```

To assign to identifiers that have already been declared, you can write

```
[populations, countries, states, counties] = await Promise.all([
   '/api/population',
   '/api/data/Country',
   '/api/data/State',
   '/api/data/County'
].map(api => fetch(api)));
```

Comment: Thank you! so a forEach wouldn't be the right thing to do, right?
Also, is it common practice to have Promise.all handle all promises?

Comment: Yes it is a common practice. The problem with for each is that it doesn't return a value - the alternative would actually be map or reduce